# What does label do in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pyautogui

I have some questions about the following code:

```py
from tkinter import *

def create_window():
    new_window = Tk()
    old_window.destroy()
    Label(new_window,text='hi').pack()
old_window = Tk()

Button(old_window,text="create new window!",command=create_window).pack()

old_window.mainloop()
```

Why is **label** used here instead of just writing **text=** in **new_window**? And how does **label** actually work?

I searched for this topic on YouTube, but I did not find an answer to my question. They just write a label without any explanation as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Label is a widget that implements a display box where you can place text or images. The text displayed by this widget can be updated at any time you want.

So this line:

```
Label(new_window,text='hi').pack()
```

Does the following: create a text saying hi in the window called new_window, then displays it by using the .pack() method